# Cannot add NT Authority login into SQL Server

Tags: active-directory, sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2014 on a Windows 2012 R2 instance. I named the instance SQLExpress. After installing SQL Server, I joined this machine to an Active Directory domain and logged in using the enterprise admin(Administrator). Now I want to add a **login** for **NT Authority\System** using the SQL Server Management studio. When I go into add it, I get a permission error stating that the user does not have permission to do that. I use Windows Authentication method and the current user is shown as **DOMAIN_NAME\Administrator**

What might be the cause of this and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe UAC? Try to start the SQL Management Studio with "Start as Administrator"

Comment: i tried it. I get to see only Builtin\Users and sa.

Comment: Does the Windows user have the SA role in SQL?

Comment: yes. sa is present in login

Comment: That wasn't the question. Does the Windows user you've logged into the SQL server as have the SA *role*, as in, is the Windows user a *System Administrator* for the *SQL Server*. Domain permissions are separate from SQL Server permissions.

Comment: no. the user does not have a sysadmin role. how can i add it? I actually installed SQL Server using a local administrator(SERVER_NAME\Administrator) and I am now logging in using the domain administrator (ORG\Administrator)

Comment: Log in with the Local Administrator, grant SA to Domain Admin. You could also just create the login for system as Local Admin.